# How to differentiate between same pattern with different number of occurrences using regex?

Tags: python, regex, bash, grep

I would like to know how to make difference between lines of unequal number of columns.
For example:

```
 100.00000     150.00000
 18.1170      998.00      575.31    -1318.75      575.31
```

An expected result would be to return line 1 or line 2, but not both.
The expression should recognize that the first line has two floats, and the second is composed of five floats of arbitrary length with arbitrary number of white spaces in between.

A solution in python (or whatever) would be to split the lines and counting the elements of a list, but I would like to know if I could write an expression to identify lines of various number of columns.

I tried `\d+\.\d+` but off course this obviously does not make difference between lines of different number of columns.

I also tried something like this, (as whitespace-number-whitespace-number mask):

```
^\s+[0-9]+\.[0-9]+\s+[0-9]+\.[0-9]+\s+[0-9]+\.[0-9]+
```

which is also not what I would like to have.

or using a group `(\d+\.[0-9]+\s)+`

Comment: Why are you forcing your thinking into using regex? I don't think you'll do much better than `len(split(line))`

Comment: @PaulMcGuire - I wrote in the question that I have such a solution and that I am interested in a regex way, if there is any. Is is wrong to be curious?

Comment: @EdMorton I am interested in regex, and if there is any solution to this problem. These lines are from a random file, it doesn't matter if there are the first two lines or not. I think its clear, I would like to know if regex can differentiate between line 1 and 2 from line 3 and 4.

Comment: I would also like to know why down vote? What aspect of a question is it not fulfilling?

Comment: @EdMorton - thank You Ed, I tried to simplified the question, hope it is more clearer.  A 'yes' answer is fine, but it might not be useful :)

Comment: @Mofi - I would like to see an expression that can match either the first or the second line so used in grep it will return line 1 or line 2. The example is general, and any working answer is fine. I will be able to apply it to my problem.

Comment: @EdMorton - Actually, You are right, I wanted to do the impossible. I wanted to know if I can differentiate lines by the number of occurrences of a pattern, like `(\d+\.\d+)` would identify the floats and I thought that maybe there is a way to identify the occurrence of that group n times with an expression.

Comment: Generally, you can't count inside regular expressions (you can in Perl, but that's a different subject). The best you could do is to read a line, get all the matches using `[+-]?(?:\d+(?:\.\d*)?|\.\d+)` then using split (with same regex), which returns what's between the numbers, validate the numbers are separated by spaces or whatever. I wouldn't fret about this, computers are pretty fast nowadays..

Comment: In the end, there is no _counting_ capacity built into regular expressions. Dot-Net has capture collections, PCRE has the `\G` construct. These however are after-the-fact result analysis. In reality, they would be equivalent to using split. So, you might as well use split anyway. Perl however, synergizes code constructs inside expressions (like `(?:[+-]?(?:\d+(?:\.\d*)?|\.\d+)(?{ ++var; })\s+)+`) which counts as you go.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This regular expression finds lines with **less or more than 5 values**.

```
^[\t ]*(?:(?:-?[\d.]+[\t ]*){0,4}|(?:-?[\d.]+[\t ]+){5}[-\d.].*)$
```

**Explanation:**

`^` ... start each search at beginning of a line.

`[\t ]*` ... match 0 or more tabs or spaces at beginning of the line.

It is not good to use here `\s` as this character class matches any whitespace character which includes the newline characters carriage return and line-feed and the search expression should never match a string spanning over multiple lines.

`(?:`...`|`...`)` ... an OR expression in a non capturing group.

**The first argument of OR expression is for finding lines with 0 to 4 values.**

`(?:`...`){0,4}` ... the expression inside the round brackets must be matched at least 0 times, but not more than 4 times.

`-?` ... match an optionally existing hyphen character (used as minus).

`[\d.]+[\t ]*` ... match any digit or dot 1 or more times each followed by **0** or more tabs or spaces.

**The second argument of OR expression is for finding lines with 6 or more values.**

`(?:`...`){5}` ... the expression inside the round brackets must be matched exactly 5 times.

`-?` ... match an optionally existing hyphen character (used as minus).

`[\d.]+[\t ]+` ... match any digit or dot 1 or more times each followed by **1** or more tabs or spaces.

`[-\d.].*` ... match either a hyphen character, or any digit or a dot and **0** or more characters up to end of the line. If there is after 5 values at least 1 other value character, the line contains definitely more than 5 values.

`$` ... matched string must end at end of a line (or end of file).

**Expression to match also line termination**

The following extended expression can be used to match also the line termination of type DOS/Windows (carriage return + line-feed) or UNIX (only line-feed) or MAC (only carriage return) in case of the line with wrong number of values should be deleted completely from file.

```
^[\t ]*(?:(?:-?[\d.]+[\t ]*){0,4}|(?:-?[\d.]+[\t ]+){5}[-\d.].*)$(?:\r?\n|\r)?
```

The question mark after non capturing OR expression for the 3 types of line terminations result in matching also the last line of the file if this line has no line termination and this string at end of file has not exactly 5 floating point values.

**Find lines with exactly 5 floating point values:**

For completeness the opposite for finding lines with exactly 5 values:

```
^[\t ]*(?:-?[\d.]+[\t ]+){4}-?[\d.]+[\t ]*$
```

Or with matching also line termination (or just the 5 values at end of file):

```
^[\t ]*(?:-?[\d.]+[\t ]+){4}-?[\d.]+[\t ]*$(?:\r?\n|\r)?
```

---

But if the tab/space separated values file contains for example

```
100.0000     150.0000
100.0000     150.0000    200.0000
 18.1170     998.00      575.31      -1318.75       575.31
-54.1270     -13.20        8.45         27.7564    9863.6246
 -2.84      7520.8843    -74.8305      340.4149     237.7302
935.224      738.720     942.9         270.0034       8.3053    2943.20
```

and the task is to mark

- with an exclamation mark each line with a different number of floating point values in comparison to next line

and

- with an equal sign each line with with an equal number of floating point values in comparison to next line as well as the last line in the file

at beginning of the line with an additional space to get as output

```
! 100.0000     150.0000
! 100.0000     150.0000    200.0000
=  18.1170     998.00      575.31      -1318.75       575.31
= -54.1270     -13.20        8.45         27.7564    9863.6246
!  -2.84      7520.8843    -74.8305      340.4149     237.7302
= 935.224      738.720     942.9         270.0034       8.3053    2943.20
```

using just a single regular expression, the answer is:

**This is impossible.**

Comment: thank you @Mofi for the thorough answer and the concluding remark. 
`^[\t ]*(?:-?[\d.]+[\t ]+){2,}-?[\d.]+[\t]*$` will match the second line of my example (more than two floats) 
https://regex101.com/r/GQHsQu/2